# AttributeError: module 'Trial1' has no attribute 'Demo'

Tags: attributeerror

I am a beginner in Python, I have faced the Attribute Error when running the following code. I have put the whole Trial1 inside Trial2 folder. The following code will not return error when

```
d = T1.Demo()
```

is removed from Trial2.py
Following are the complete code.

```
"""code in Trial1"""
class Demo:
def __init__(self, a=22, b=33):
    self.__a = a
    self.__b = b

def do_something(self):
    return self.__a + self.__b

def pValue(self):
    print(self.__a)


"""code in Trial2"""
import Trial1 as T1
d = T1.Demo()
```

I am sorry for my trival question as compared to other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out after a few second. This importing method seems like it can only import another .py file in the current Trial2 folder. Hope it helps for other people who face similar problem.